# How to identify elements which have the same class, but unique names?

Tags: jquery, filter

There are multiple elements using the same `class` name.

Also, they have a unique name. For example, one is `org_name dev`. The other one is `org_name mar`.

How can I distinguish between two elements?

Comment: [By using "attribute * selectors".](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of such a document?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses CSS selectors for choosing elements.
In your case I'd use:

```
$('.classname[name=dev]')
```

for the first one and

```
$('.classname[name=mar]')
```

for the second.
However, name is not a unique attribute so I suppose you ment they have a unique ID, in that case I'll choose them using

```
$('#dev')
$('#mar')
```

You can look here for a more detailed review of CSS selectors:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: thanks a lot. [this site](http://www.susiro.com/converter) is also great for people who want convert units.